# How do I use Adobe Fonts (Creative Cloud) in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, fonts

In Inkscape 1.1 on Windows 10, Adobe Fonts (Creative Cloud, formerly 'Typekit') do not appear to be available in the Font menu, and are listed with a ⚠ symbol.

How do I use Adobe Fonts on Inkscape 1.1 on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According](https://www.reddit.com/r/Inkscape/comments/n0bl5w/comment/howyzx4/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) to reddit.com user u/Rare-Review-9211,

## Solution for Windows 10

In Inkscape 1.1, add the following path under

> Edit > Preferences > tool > text

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\CoreSync\plugins\livetype\r
```